# Two background colors for layout with horizontally centered content

Tags: html, css

[image]
Referencing the diagram above, I would like to create the following webpage layout:

- column 1 and column 4 are fluid margins
- column 2 + column 3 = a fixed width container used to display content
- column 1 and column 2 are of the same background color
- column 3 and column 4 are of the same background color

So far, I've tried using some `position:fixed` hacks for column 1 and column 4, but I hope there's a better way in achieving this. [My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wLe4bj40/)

Comment: Why don't you just create a div that contains column 2 & 3 and set the margin properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the best way to do this is to simply use a background gradient.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
     <div id="left"></div>
     <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, red 0%, red 50%, blue 50%, blue 100%);
}
```

Update fiddle in case anyone is interested: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wLe4bj40/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try the css with setting the appropriate ids for the column divs.

```
#col1{
  /* left column */
  width: 25%; /* adjust as much as you want */
  display: block;
}

#col2{
  /* container for both middle columns */
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

#col3{
  /* right column */
  width: auto;
  float: right;
  display: block;
}

#col4{
  /* center left column */
  width: 250px; /* set appropriate width */
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

#col5{
  /* center right column */
  width: 350px; /* set appropriate width */
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
```

Your html will look like below:

```
<div id='col1'></div>
<div id='col2'>
  <div id='col4'></div>
  <div id='col5'></div>
</div>
<div id='col3'></div>
```